# Uniform_real does not accept numeric_limits::lowest()

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I've got a line:

```
std::uniform_real_distribution<T> distribution(std::numeric_limits<T>::lowest(), 
                                               std::numeric_limits<T>::max());
```

It compiles but crashes on Debug(VS 2017CE). My guess is that, according to documentation of `std::uniform_real_distribution`:

> Requires that `a ≤ b` and `b-a ≤ std::numeric_limits<RealType>::max()`

when my `b` is `::max()` and `a` is `::lowest()`, condition:

> `b-a ≤ std::numeric_limits<RealType>::max()`

is not fulfilled as `b-a` basically doubles the value of `max`. Is there any work around for this so that I will keep such a wide numbers range? `::min()` works perfectly but omits negative values. Problem occurs for floating numbers only.

Comment: So you want a uniform distribution over the whole range of `T`?

Comment: @hellow Exactly. Might be a bit smaller but as wide as possible.

Comment: There might be a smarter solution, but if everything fails, you can use two ranges (negative and positive half axis) and randomly pick one to poll from. Or, for IEEE754 equivalently, use [0, max] and randomly flip the sign.

Comment: I've got an answer but I'd like to ask what behavior you are looking for first.  A range of `[lowest, max)` will produce most of its results closer to the two ends since there are so many more numbers towards the ends then there is in the middle.  Do you want that behavior or do you want smaller numbers to have the same chance of showing up?

Comment: @NathanOliver Most results having a big magnitude would be expected when using a uniform distribution, wouldn't it?

Comment: @NathanOliver I want values from edges of range. I don't want any particular number, just maximum width of range.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Some people don't expect that behavior

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the range `[-1, 1]` and then multiply that by `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` to get the actual number.  This lets you satisfy the `b-a ≤ std::numeric_limits<RealType>::max()` requirement.

```
auto dis = std::uniform_real_distribution<T> dis(-1, std::nextafter(1, std::numeric_limits<T>::max()));
return dis(eng) * std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
```

This won't give you all possible floating point values but it will give you a good number of them distributed like a `uniform_int_distribution` would.

Comment: Are you sure this can actually hit every possible value?

Comment: @BaummitAugen I'm fairly certain it doesn't but it behaves like a `uniform_int_distribution` for the range of values.  Depends on how the OP actually wants the results distributed.

Comment: That seems kind of self-contradicting. For a uniform distribution on say the range of `double`, every number should have a positive probability (which depends on its magnitude of course).

Comment: @BaummitAugen I've never seen a `uniform_real_distribution` implementation which actually achieves that property. The normal approach is just `u01 * (max-min) + min`.

Comment: @Sneftel Possible, never checked that in detail. But it's the way it should be, at least in theory.

Comment: For my needs this solution also go really well. Thank you very much. I will leave it open for a while to see if anyone know why it is even happening.

Comment: @PStarczewski Know why what is happening?

Comment: @PStarczewski it (the crash) is happening because you are violating the documented requirements of the distribution?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I am not sure. I have just tested it on linux and works fine in contrast to windows. Can not figure out why tho.

Comment: @PStarczewski It is undefined behavior to violate the contract.  The contract states that `b-a ≤ std::numeric_limits<RealType>::max()` and if you violate that then all bets are off.  It could work, it could fail to compile, it could crash, it could give you wrong results, it could let my dogs out of the yard and I have to spend a half hour chasing them down.  Undefined behavior means it can do what it wants.

Comment: I mean, I thought I knew why it was not working, however out of curiosity tested it on Linux and worked perfectly. So now I am not sure if my diagnosis was correct.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for explanation!

Answer (score 10):

One simple solution, at least for the common IEEE-754 floating point numbers, would be randomly flipping the sign of a random non-negative number:

```
std::uniform_real_distribution<T> distribution(0., 
                                               std::numeric_limits<T>::max());
auto rn = distribution(eng);
return someRandomFlag ? rn : -rn;
```

where `someRandomFlag` is chosen uniformly from `{true, false}`.

Comment: I guess I will go for it as it's simple and clean. Thanks. However I will wait with accepting this as solution as I'm just curious why it is happening in the first place and maybe someone will know.

Comment: @PStarczewski You already know why it's happening. `uniform_real_distribution` requires that `b-a <= max`.

Comment: Note that this could result in a ridiculously small over-weighing of `0`, as 0 and -0 are equal.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont while 0. == -0., they are not the same number.

Comment: @DanM. • same number (mathematically speaking), different representations.  The `-0.` one occurring in certain edge cases.  Treated the same... mostly.  Sometimes a bit tricky to distinguish between them when such distinguishing is desired.

Comment: "Math" is not relevant here since float/dobules are not Real numbers. For computers, those are different. It probably doesn't matter for most purposes, but it's worth knowing. For example, while `uniform_real_distribution` is "uniform" certain numbers would have much higher chance of being selected than the others just because floating point distribution is not uniform.

Comment: @DanM. Each float can be treated as representing a range of real numbers; uniform real distribution, in theory, can give each floating point number a chance commesurate with the measure of the represented set of real numbers.  "Math" is quite relevant here; when ignored, you get nonsense.

Comment: @Yakk - Adam Nevraumont yup, but you'll get non-uniform numbers that would only be uniform in respect to the represented intervals. It's an important distinction. This discussion stemmed from "ridiculously small over-weighing of 0". If we start talking about "weights" it's doesn't really make sense to talk about Real numbers anymore. computer doubles are already heavily non-uniform (in a "probability to generate this number" kind of way) with any such distribution.

Comment: @DanM. Probability on uncountable sets is expressed as measures of the subsets; dividing the real numbers into equivalence classes and using floats as the name of the equivalence class both makes perfect sense and is the reasonable way to talk about real uniform distribution of floating point values (or really, any real uniform distribution; all reals have a probability of 0 of being selected in a uniform distribution). All of this makes perfect sense and follows directly from the "Math". Your objections seem to betray confusion about measure theory and probability theory, which is common.

Comment: @Yakk - Adam Nevraumont there is no uncountable sets on PCs. And it doesn't matter whether the underlying math "checks out" (I'm not questioning that), but the programmer doesn't deal with ideal math systems. It might be greatly surprising for a programmer to find out that some value X is generated x1000 times as much as some other value Y in supposedly uniform distribution (he doesn't care whether it belongs to a class representing a x1000 bigger interval or not)

Comment: @DanM. Yes, programmers who don't understand what "uniform real distribution" means won't understand what it does.  It is both possible and expected that "uniform real distribution" means "uniform real distribution".  The real numbers that a given floating point value represents (ie, would round to that floating point) are well defined under the IEEE standard.  Regardless, this isn't productive.  Goodbye.